# When and where to release a Singleton instance in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I am not sure if i am asking the right question or not.
I have a singleton class as below:

```
static DBHandler *dbHandler = nil;

+(DBHandler *)sharedDBHandler {

    @synchronized(self) {
        if(nil == dbHandler) {

            dbHandler = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return dbHandler;
}
```

When and where to release a Singleton instance in Objective-C ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to release singleton instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often they are located in static memory which means they are handled differently. See this question:

[Objective-C/iPhone Memory Management Static Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606854/objective-c-iphone-memory-management-static-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Never and Nowhere. Unless in the code that uses the singleton object you retained it for some inexplicable reason.