# Memory Management in Objective-C with static objects

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C/iPhone Memory Management Static Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606854/objective-c-iphone-memory-management-static-variables)

I'm looking through a contractor's code who is no longer with us and I'm not sure how to handle memory management in this case.  There is a

```
static NSArray *_sharedSample = nil;
```

declared in a .m file.  Then they do

```
_sharedSample = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:someinfo here, nil] retain];
```

So in this case, where is the release?  I've searched for _sharedSample throughout the project, and I do not see a [_sharedSample release];.  Do static objects work differently?  I thought I'd have to release it somewhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606854/objective-c-iphone-memory-management-static-variables

Answer (score 1):

A static variable is effectively an application global, no matter how many objects, methods or functions know about it.

You have the option to just leave it.  The memory will be freed by the system when the app quits.

You should initialize static variables to nil (zero) in the declaration line as you have here. Static variables are allocated earlier in the launch process than the call to the app's main() function. This means that no allocation pools will yet exist.

If you attempt to create an Objective-C object before the first pool is created you may cause a memory leak.  (You will see a "just leaking" message in the debugger console if you do.)

If you do release a static variable along the way, you should also immediately set it to nil to prevent errors with over-releasing or dangling pointers.